# Create a pandas data frame and fill relevant values in it from a reference data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame called `df` that looks like this:

[image]

I need to create a new data frame / modify the existing one so that it will expand the values in `df['SOV']` to show all values from 1-80 like this:

[image]

The values of `SOV = 5` have been backfilled for SOV 1-5 in the new data frame. The values of `SOV = 10` have been backfilled for SOV 6-10 in the new data frame and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```py
# assign ranges to SOV column (from previous row's SOV until current row's SOV)
df['SOV'] = [range(s+1,e+1) for s,e in zip(pd.Series([0]).append(df['SOV']), df['SOV'])]
# explode the ranges (the other columns will be copied across rows)
df = df.explode('SOV')
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is always necessary generate 5 new rows is possible use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) by `5`, generate new rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and then rewrite column manually:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(5)].copy()
df['SOV'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
```

Or for general solution repeat rows by difference by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html)and generate column `SOV` by counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['SOV'].diff().fillna(df['SOV']))].copy()
df['SOV'] -= df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(ascending=False)
```